# How droping a table from DB affects the views

Tags: mysql, sql-server

A veiw is created on table Student.
If i drop the student table will the veiw also drop ? If not what will be the situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view remains but is invalid.  You must explicitly drop the view.

Answer (score 0):

When a table gets dropped all data, indexes, and linked information will be deleted as well.It's been like a row in DB which use delete all the relative column and all the information that was linked to it will be deleted as well.

> When a table is dropped, privileges granted specifically for the table
>   are not automatically dropped. They must be dropped manually.

Be careful with this statement! It removes the table definition and all table data. For a partitioned table, it permanently removes the table definition, all its partitions, and all data stored in those partitions. It also removes partition definitions associated with the dropped table.

Comment: The view remains though.  What happens is that when you query the view it throws an error about how the underlying table does not exist.